# URL on CMS page not always working

Tags: magento-1.9, url, cms

I am developing a store in magento 1.9.1, local on MAMP

The site is set up in navigation bar with a store-button which shows all the products (or a selection), category-buttons etc. In each category-button there are subcategories, drop down buttons like brands or designers.

All products are grouped with various sizes.

On the product page I have placed a “more about” link to a CMS page. This page contains more information and there are images of the other products in this brand. The images are links to their individual pages.

An image with link looks like this:

```
</td>
<td><a class="product-image" title="Orange" href="{{store direct_url="orange.html"}}"><img alt="Orange" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/dd4.jpg"}}" height="125" width="125" /></a>
<h3 class="product-name"><a title="Orange" href="{{store direct_url="orange.html"}}">Orange</a></h3>
</td>
```

It works fine and so does yellow, green, blue etc. the url in the store is like  - - /magento/blue.html

Suddenly a new one, “red” gives a 404. Refresh works fine for all except “red” which is still 404.

From “store” I click “red” it opens the product page and I copy the URL from that page - - /magento/store/dave-david.html  (dave-david is the category url key) and change the url in the CMS page to this

`<a class="product-image" title="Red" href="{{store direct_url="store/dave-david.html"}}">`  - it works fine. I can remove - store - in url,  "{{store direct_url="dave-david.html"}}" works, too.

(The “Orange” link in store is - - /magento/store/orange.html)

Going from the “category” “red” button I get this url - - /category1/dave-david-930.html and that works fine when entered in the CMS page.

A bit strange, 930 is the id number, well not quite it is 922. Replacing 930 with 922 works, but it generates 930 when entered.

Removing category1/ and use - - /dave-david-930.html gives 404

Now the drop down button category1 - Dave David URL is - - /magento/category1/dave-david.html
and change URL in CMS page to `{{store direct_url=“category1/dave-david/dave-david.html"}}` works as well but remove category1/ gives 404.

I have googled for days but not been able to find anything like this.

I can set up the CMS page and adjust the links that is not working with links from “store” or “category” but somehow I have a feeling this could easy conflict in some browsers.

Has anyone experienced the same problem and found a solution? Help will be much appreciated.

---

This is missing

Image with links should be

```
<a class="product-image" title="Orange" href="{{store direct_url="orange.html"}}"><img alt="Orange" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/dd4.jpg"}}" height="125" width="125" />
```

---

I do not know why this platform is skipping the html.

I try again

```
<a class="product-image" title="Orange" href="{{store direct_url="orange.html"}}"><img alt="Orange" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/dd4.jpg"}}" height="125" width="125" /></a>
```

Orange

---

Sorry new to this tried to add some html in the text. This site interpreted the html. I hav tried to remove the question to make it right, no succes.
Removed some of the missing html plus some signs and the part of the link in question seems to show.

```
<a class="product-image" title="Orange" href="{{store direct_url="orange.html"}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be an issue with the URL itself.

Have you checked that there isn't an accidental rewrite rule for the red.html page?

If you don't have a lot of custom redirect rules you could try to go into the database and flush the core_url_rewrite table, and afterwards re-index.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.

This has been quite troublesome. I have tried almost everything, deleted files, flushed core_url_rewrite etc. 

Changing the URL in the grouped product in Manage Product, even when I remove mark in Create Permanent Redirect for old URL box. I will get a 404 or it generates its own url and gives something completely different.

The flushing did something good. I was able to change  some of the URLs but not all.

Finally I found a way. I deleted the faulty grouped product and created a new. It works but sometimes I have to rename the URL to make it work. 

Thanks Sven